# My 'p' element is not appearing in my 'div' element that I appeanded it to, any solutions?

Tags: javascript

```js
base = document.createElement('div');
document.body.append(base);
base.style.width = '100px';
base.style.height = '150px';
base.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
base.style.color = 'white';
base.style.opacity = '0.8';
base.style.borderRadius = '5px';
base.style.fontFamily = 'arial';
baseHeading = document.createElement('p');
document.body.base.append(baseHeading);
baseHeading.innerText = 'Controid';
```

My text is not showing like its supposed to. ALSO can I make the div draggable?

Comment: Do you see an error message in the console of your browser? (There should most certainly be one)

Comment: the baseHeading isn't appearing, i don't see 'controid'.

Comment: no error in console

Comment: `ALSO can I make the div draggable?` on a Q&A site like stackoverflow you should not combine multiple questions in one.

Comment: What is `document.body.base`? I get an error from `document.body.base.append(baseHeading);`

Comment: document.body.base is the base div element

Comment: Accessing elements via `document.body` works, but is a 25+ year old API. Instead, just query for your element: `document.querySelector("#base");`

Comment: As a  matter of personal preference, I tend to define the properties of the element that I am adding before it is added to the DOM.  I tend to think that it makes the code more readable.  Also consider using some comments and line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the `p` element to the `div` element, not the base element. Use this:

```js
base = document.createElement('div');
document.body.append(base);
base.style.width = '100px';
base.style.height = '150px';
base.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
base.style.color = 'white';
base.style.opacity = '0.8';
base.style.borderRadius = '5px';
base.style.fontFamily = 'arial';
baseHeading = document.createElement('p');
base.append(baseHeading);
baseHeading.innerText = 'Controid';
```